# Kubernetes Helm define multiline init container command

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I’m trying to organize my charts and migrate all the `initContainers` into a helper named chart **_scripts.tlp**.

I have an `initContainers` step in **proxy-deployment.yaml** that is waiting until my broker service initializes like so:

```sh
      # This init container will wait for at least one broker to be ready before proceeding
      # with deploying the rest of the proxy service
      - name: wait-broker-ready
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        command: ["bash", "-c"]
        args:
          - >-
            for i in {0..10}; do
              broker_pods="$(nslookup -timeout=10 {{ template "service.fullname" . }}-{{ .Values.broker.component }} | grep Name | wc -l)"
              if [[ ${broker_pods} -ge 1 ]]; then
                break
              fi
              sleep 30;
            done;
```

I am trying to rewrite it like so:

```sh
      # This init container will wait for at least one broker to be ready before proceeding
      # with deploying the rest of the proxy service
      - name: wait-broker-ready
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        command: ["bash", "-c"]
        args:
          - >-
            {{ template  "service.waitBrokerReady"}}
```

I have the following names template **_scripts.tlp**:

```sh
{{/*
Wait until at least one broker instances is initialized
*/}}
{{ define "service.waitBrokerReady" }}
for i in {0..10}; do
  broker_pods="$(nslookup -timeout=10 {{ template "service.fullname" . }}-{{ .Values.broker.component }} | grep Name | wc -l)"
  if [[ ${broker_pods} -ge 1 ]]; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 30;
done;
{{- end }}
```

Unfortunately, the fact that this is a multiline command and there are spaces demarcations, I see `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml`.

I have tried several variations with `printf`, but not sure how to pass nested templates and often see `Error: parse error at (service/templates/_functions.tpl:6): "-p" in command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution seems to be working for me:

**_scripts.tlp**:

```sh
{{/*
Wait until at least one broker instances is initialized
*/}}
{{- define "service.waitBrokerReady" }}
- >-
  for i in {0..10}; do
    broker_pods="$(nslookup -timeout=10 {{ template "service.fullname" . }}-{{ .Values.broker.component }} | grep Name | wc -l)"
    if [[ ${broker_pods} -ge 1 ]]; then
      break
    fi
    sleep 30;
  done;
{{- end -}}
```

**proxy-deployment.yaml**:

```sh
      # This init container will wait for at least one broker to be ready before proceeding
      # with deploying the rest of the proxy service
      - name: wait-broker-ready
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        command: ["bash", "-c"]
        args:
            {{- include "pulsar.waitBrokerReady" . | indent 10 }}
```

At first, I wasn't able to figure out why the include didn't work, so I used the combination of `squote` command to figure out the alignment and then you can add the `replace` to check if the template actually would work:

`            {{- include "pulsar.waitBrokerReady" . | squote | indent 10 | replace "'" "" }}

Once, it does template, you can remove the `squote` and `replace`.